# how to convert json to model class in dart like following image. It have digits of keyvalue header

Tags: json, class, dart, model

the app.quicktype.io cannot convert.
they are converting and skip the digit class name

```
class ScoreCardModel {
  bool? status;
  String? msg;
  Data? data;

  ScoreCardModel({this.status, this.msg, this.data});

  ScoreCardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    msg = json['msg'];
    data = json['data'] = Data.fromJson(json['data']);
  }
}

class Data {
  String? result;
  Scorecard? scorecard;

  Data({this.result, this.scorecard});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    result = json['result'];
    scorecard = json['scorecard'] != null
        ? Scorecard.fromJson(json['scorecard'])
        : null;
  }
}
```

the quicktype cannot work with digits, I don't know why is this. I think they are in the developing stage. I Have the answer. I'm[image] looking for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://jsontodart.com/, They are just including digit as model(Class) name. But You have to rename the model name like follows,

```
class 1 {
    String score;
    String wicket;
    String ball;

    1({this.score, this.wicket, this.ball});

    1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        score = json['score'];
        wicket = json['wicket'];
        ball = json['ball'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['score'] = this.score;
        data['wicket'] = this.wicket;
        data['ball'] = this.ball;
        return data;
    }
}
```

to

```
class teamA {
    String score;
    String wicket;
    String ball;

    teamA({this.score, this.wicket, this.ball});

    teamA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        score = json['score'];
        wicket = json['wicket'];
        ball = json['ball'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['score'] = this.score;
        data['wicket'] = this.wicket;
        data['ball'] = this.ball;
        return data;
    }
}
```